# Can the subquery be simplified/optimized?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

Here's a simplified version of a query I run. I've removed a bunch of key/value pairs for simplicity. The constraint is that I can't change anything outside of the `ARRAY` function; but the `ARRAY` function and everything inside is fair game. I want to remove the subqueries if at all possible; and if not speed up the query as much as possible.

```
SELECT json_build_object('last', max(day), 'missing_days', ARRAY(
             SELECT distinct to_char(dates, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
             FROM generate_series('2009-12-20', CURRENT_DATE, interval '1 day') AS dates
             WHERE dates NOT IN (SELECT day FROM records))
       ) AS jsobj
FROM records;
```

I thought I remembered from my database design classes that you should be able to use columns from the records table in the sub-query but I could be mistaken, or that might be database dependent, or I could have been trying the wrong syntax; anyway it didn't work when I tried it.

Comment: You can remove the `DISTINCT`. The values are already distinct and even ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can refer to rows of higher levels in a subquery. But that would not solve your problem since you need to consider the *whole table*, not just the current row.

It's not completely clear what the query is trying to achieve and data types (table definition!) are also missing. Be aware that your invocation of `generate_series()` returns `timestamptz`, which is cast to `date` (I assume) and this cast depends on your current `timezone` setting. Results for the same query may be different with a different setting for the calling session.

It's a bit cleaner and cheaper to work with `timestamp` to begin with. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

And `NOT IN (<subquery>)` is almost always a bad choice. There are faster options which are less error-prone. `NOT IN` carries traps for NULL values.

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Each of these queries should be faster. The winner depends on data distribution in your table. Test both:

Query 1 (returns `text` like your original):

```
SELECT to_char(day, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2015-12-20', LOCALTIMESTAMP, interval '1 day') d(day)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM records WHERE day = d.day);
```

Query 2 (returns `date`):

```
SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2015-12-20', LOCALTIMESTAMP, '1 day')::date AS day
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT day FROM records;   -- data types must match
```

Comment: The only column that my question needs to care about is day which is of type `date`. The output of the query I posted is exactly what I want, but I want to get it as efficiently as possible. The data is dense, one record per day for every day since the first record (unless there's a problem, in which case a few days might be missing near the current date).

Comment: I wound up using the except all variant, it was the fastest currently, and the query planner said the other version had two sorts which would be a worse than linear slowdown as the table grows.